# Debugging! SVG logo & tooltip bug

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, tooltip

I am pretty new at editing and embedding SVG to webpages. My client is a graphic designer so he created an svg logo for his website and wanted me embed it to his nav bar.

I am also using Bootstrap and as part of the development I am using bootstrap tooltips. However, once i embed the svg and edit the co-ordinates via viewbox, I encountered a problem with one of my tooltips.

The tooltip seems to be buggy with this particular logo. The rest of them are okay but for some reason I cannot figure out how to fix this one.

I have uploaded the website today for testing purposes and you can see the issue on http://edizorac.com/

The problematic logo is the second one on the navigation bar and you can also see my code through web inspector.

Any help/recommendation is appreciated!!

Thanks in advance :)

Update:

Sorry for any inconveniences. The svg code is as follows:

```
<li>
  <a href="#projects">
    <span>
        <svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" x="0px" y="0px" width="70px" height="60px" viewBox="50 40 90 120" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Projects">
            <polygon fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="33.493,81.046 96.934,46.112 88.647,82.874 57.203,117.371 52.946,86.674 99.573,74.629 81.325,117.276 37.909,101.254"/>
            <polyline fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="96.451,81.928 114.361,106.172 112.365,112.871 82.791,113.852 "/>
            <line fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="95.854" y1="47.473" x2="37.909" y2="101.254"/>
        </svg>
    </span>
   </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I suggest you have a [read over this](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) and also have a [look at this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html) to help you with SVG's

Change the first line of your SVG block to:

```
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" x="0px" y="0px" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="30 47 85 70" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Projects">
```

You made the following mistakes:

- You had the height and width set incorrectly compared to the other SVG's (Height you had defined: **60px** & Width you had defined **70px**)
- Your viewBox property was set incorrectly so the elements didn't align properly

Comment: You don't need version or baseProfile, 0 is the default value for x, y and there's no such thing as a title attribute in SVG, titles are child elements.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm just working with what was given. Go on the site and replace it with what's their it works.

Comment: Yes, but your answer should suggest best practice shouldn't it?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes - Although all everybody in this community seems to do is criticize each other. My motto is "If it works and it's safe. Leave it". Anyway why don't you leave your answer?

Comment: It wouldn't really be significantly better functionally than your answer, which in terms of actually solving the OPs problem is absolutely fine.

Comment: @RRAWebteam Thanks alot!! That actually solved my problem and the links you have sent have been very helpful too!